# Why is my rails controller not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to run a javascript line from my controller as a response to an AJAX call :

```
respond_to do |format|
  if params[:return_to] == 'monthly_calendar'
    render js: "alert('hey Trip!');"
  else
    format.js   { render :partial => @task, layout: false }
    format.html { redirect_to things_url }
    format.json { render :json => @object.to_json }
    format.xml do
      if @task.new_record?
        render :xml => @task.errors.to_xml
      else
        render :xml => @task.to_xml, :status => '201 Created'
      end
    end
  end
```

Instead this returns a 406. Any ideas?

It most certainly goes to the correct call in this statement. But doesn't know what to do with the javascript call, and returns a 406.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to this

```
respond_to do |format|
   if params[:return_to] == 'monthly_calendar'
      format.js { render js: "alert('hey Trip!');" }
   else
  .....
```

Because you are not specifying to what format are you responding, e.g. format.html { #your code here } when params[:return_to] == 'monthly_calendar'. Check documentation of [respond_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can render a full view `task.js.erb` instead of a partial.

Here is a  good tutorial on what you are trying to accomplish:

```
http://blog.bernatfarrero.com/jquery-and-rails-3-mini-tutorial/
```

I hope it helps.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try respond to the js format:

```
format.js { render js: "alert('hey Trip!');" }
```